# Orbeon Forms Radio Button Alignment

Tags: orbeon

Can someone please tell me how to align Orbeon forms Radio Buttons to have values horizontally rather than one below the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you can go to the Control Settings, and under "Custom CSS classes":

- If you're using radio radio buttons, enter `xforms-select1-appearance-xxforms-horizontal`
- If you have checkboxes, enter `xforms-select-appearance-xxforms-horizontal`

In the future, we're planning to have a more straightforward and explicit way of doing this, most likely directly in the Control Settings dialog, and this is covered by [request for enhancement #333](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/333).