# Orbeon Forms Radio Button Alignment for "Other" option

Tags: css, orbeon

Anyone know the Custom CSS for making "radio buttons with other" horizontal instead of vertical? The CSS for horizontal radio buttons is not working for when I used "radio buttons with other."

I tried the coding from this question: [Orbeon Forms Radio Button Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369543/orbeon-forms-radio-button-alignment)

I tried this Custom CSS:  xforms-select1-appearance-xxforms-horizontal

When I used the coding for the "radio buttons", nothing happened, so I am assuming I need to change the code a little for "radio buttons with other"

Comment: Hi Brittany, what version of Orbeon Forms are you currently using? Where are you adding this CSS class? Are you doing this in Form Builder, in the Control Settings dialog, or somewhere else? And are you saying that you don't notice any difference in the way the radio buttons show after adding the class? ‑Alex

Comment: Hi Brittany, have you found a solution to this one? If not, do you have some feedback regarding the question in my previous comment? ‑Alex

Answer (score 0):

Using the `xforms-select1-appearance-xxforms-horizontal` class on Radio Buttons with "Other" will be supported in Orbeon Forms 2019.1 (and newer). For reference, this is tracked as [#4114](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4114).

[image: Horizontal radios]